# One-line real-time CPU & memory usage report terminal tool

Tags: linux, command-line, memory-management

I am working with a remote server which runs tmux. I want to be able to open a one-line pane with server memory report updated in realtime. Like `top` or `htop`. Is there such a command line utility? Is there a better alternative?

**UPDATE**

As the original formulation is somewhat ambigous, I'll explain some more. I have also added "CPU" in the title since that too would be nice, and such programs often have CPU indicators too.

1. I know what programs are running on the server, so I do not need the list of processes. That is - if memory is taken, I know what is occupying it. Simply showing some readout on how much RAM is busy would be enough. If I'll need more info, I'll refer to `htop`.
2. CPU load can also be displayed along the memory info. Again, it is a matter of about 5-6 characters per 1 core.
3. If there's more info than can fit in the line, it could swap "pages" on display.
4. The whole point is to have a tiny readout, akin to those that are rather common to reside in tray area on graphical desktops under Linux or Windows (in Windows, for example, there's a ton of programs that show that info in tray area, taking a couple of square centimeters of screen space).

All these are just wishes in the direction of what I'd like to have. Probably there's some program that can do this or something like this.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want in the memory report?

Comment: @bariumbitmap Hello! Thanks for your comment. I have updated the original question.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful clarification. A few more questions: The `free` program shows total memory usage; are you interested in percentage occupied instead? Also, how long is the line allowed to be? For example, should it be 80 columns or less, or are arbitrarily long lines allowed?

Comment: For example, would a variation on this script serve your needs? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119126/command-to-display-memory-usage-disk-usage-and-cpu-load

Comment: @bariumbitmap Wow, yes, quite probable! Did not think that that is possible with bash! This will work with some change in the formatting! I guess it can also be made to update, say 1-2 times a second in a loop so that it will run on itself in a dedicated terminal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Instead of **tmux**, try **[byobu](http://byobu.co/)**, a terminal window manager which devotes the bottom two lines of each screen to a myriad of configurable system status notifications, for which there is a terminal GUI **byobu-config**.

2) **[liquidprompt](https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt)**, an adaptive prompt for **bash** & **zsh** with various configurable status display options.